# comint-exec with very large argument list on windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, comint

I wish to start a command that has a very large argument list (10s or 100s of thousand characters) with `comint-exec` but when I do this on Windows it fails to start.

The only error is

```
apply: Spawning child process: exec format error
```

and I've confirmed that it is the argument length that causes the problem by reducing the list and the process starts up (but that's no good because I need the arguments to be able to get any use out of the process I'm spawning, which is a java command with an extremely large classpath).

This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261071 but it's not the same.

Comment: Maybe you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable instead?

Comment: that's a very good point!